# Error communicating with the remote browser on FF browser(Intermittent issue..most time code executes successfully)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to execute a simple program and facing the below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'MDVWSHERALL', ip: '172.16.160.84', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=44.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 0a47ef91-e6c0-466c-8be3-8c87570042db
```

I am not sure why I am getting this issue as my code does execute successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Please share your code as well..

Comment: if you are using latest firefox, please downgrade and re-try. make sure that firefox is installed in program files folder